# Kotlin generating priavate field: @MyAnnotation field must not be private or static

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I am learning Kotlin.

I developed one library in Java based on annotation processing. This library works perfectly on Java. My library contains annotations which the user can put on class fields. But that field should not be `private` or `static` in order to process that field.

```
@MyAnnotation
private String userName;
```

This will throw a compile-time error suggesting the user to remove the `private` modifier to be processed by my library's annotation processor.

Once user removes `private` it's working.

Now in case of Kotlin

```
@MyAnnotation
var spUserName : String? = null
```

This is generating the private field like below.

```
...
private java.lang.String spUserName;
...
```

So my annotation processor is throwing a compile-time error.

After searching the web, adding `@JvmField` on that field is working perfectly like below.

```
@JvmField
@MyAnnotation
var spUserName : String? = null
```

But I don't want my users to add one more annotation above my annotation. It increasing the code if there are so many fields.

Please suggest any other alternative to avoid `@JvmField`.

So my question is: how can I make my field non-private in Kotlin without using `@JvmField`?

Answer (score -1):

```
@MyAnnotation
public var str: String? = null
```

Add `public` modifier

I donot know why I deleted this answer. If you visited [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) you would see the default modifier for members inside class is `private`.

Comment: `public` is default modifier.